# incompatible types: RGBColor [][] cannot be converted to Double [][] -Error

Tags: java, arrays, double, tostring, rgbcolor

I need a little help with something that drives me crazy.
A little information about the code-

1. Pixel is 3 colors of red, green and blue.
2. RGBColor[][] represents an array of pixels.
3. RGBImage[][] represents an array of RGBColor. There is RGBColor object in each cell of the RGBImage[][] array.
4. convertToGrayscale() is a method which converts every pixel to its grayscale values.
5. There is also a toString() method of the RGBImage class that would print out the image with all its values- array of RGBColor objects.

**The problem** - I want the toGrayscaleArray() method to use the convertToGrayscale() method. So I built a for loop which converts every cell of the array to grayscale. but when I try to return _rgbimage which is now converted, I get compiler error-
*incompatible types: RGBColor [][] cannot be converted to Double [][]*

any help would be much appreciated.

```
    /** returns grayscale representation of the image
    * @return grayscale representation of the image
    */
    public double [][] toGrayscaleArray()
    {
    int row = _rgbimage.length;
    int col = _rgbimage[0].length;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            _rgbimage[i][j].convertToGrayscale();

        } 
    return _rgbimage; //THE COMPILER ERROR IS HERE
}
```

The toString() - the method has been tested and works properly.

```
/** creates a string of matrix which represents the image, in the following format:
 * (red,green,blue) (red,green,blue) (red,green,blue)
 * (red,green,blue) (red,green,blue) (red,green,blue)
 * (red,green,blue) (red,green,blue) (red,green,blue)
 * @return toString
 */
public String toString ()
{
    int rows = _rgbimage.length; 
    int cols = _rgbimage[0].length;
    String imageMatrix = new String("");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (j < cols-1) //checks if it's the last cell on the row
                imageMatrix += _rgbimage[i][j] + " "; //if not last cell - add space
            else 
                imageMatrix += _rgbimage[i][j]; //if last cell - don't add space             
        }
        imageMatrix += "\n";
    }
    return imageMatrix;
    }
```

Comment: I would think the error message itself is self-explanatory Seeing as you use String imageMatrix = new String(""); I would recommend you familiarize yourself with the basics before jumping to image processing

Comment: It is, but I don't know how to fix it. I wouldn't have asked otherwise.

Comment: either you change the returntype of that method, or you build an array of the correct type to return

Comment: can't change the return type, this is the signature and it cannot be changed.
how can i build an array of the correct type?

Comment: double[][] corrected = new double[x][y]; you'll need to figure out the values of x and y, and the values to assign to the elements

Comment: now it says RGBColor cannot be converted to Double. Kind of the same issue

Comment: no. that's because you are trying to store a wrong value

Comment: which RGBColor class/interface are you using?